# Keeping a sliding menu open on mouseover

Tags: jquery, animation, hover, mouseout, slidingdrawer

I'm trying to convert an existing menu system which is loaded with inline Javascript into new, more efficient, code using only jQuery.

I have a horizontal bar with rollover images.  I have a hidden field in the page containing an integer value.  When a page is loaded, the corresponding menu is loaded with a "sticky" version of the image and all other menu items swap images on mouse enter & leave.  It was loaded with tons of inline Javascript and a monster Javascript file that was tedious to convert every time I created a new site.

I successfully converted this all to jQuery where I was also able to disable the click on the sticky menu item.  Now I can simply set some variables and easily customize it per each site's design.

Working great...

Now comes a new issue.  One design contains a bunch of sliding drawers under each menu image.  The sliding animations are handled by an external JS file and the menu drawers themselves are each just a DIV containing the content nested inside a container DIV.

So then I wrote some simple stuff for jQuery that animates the DIV and slides it in and out on mouse hover for the menu images.

The problem is that I cannot seem to solve the problem of the mouse moving away from the menu image and down into the menu drawer without the drawer closing.  I understand the "why?"... I am leaving the image which triggers the animation to close the drawer before I can get inside.  If I apply the hover animations to the drawer container it simply creates a zone under the menu which also triggers the animation, and I don't want that either.  It seems to be turning into a more complex problem with jQuery.  All this was working fine with the inline Javascript... you could just move your mouse from the image into the adjacent open drawer without triggering the function to close it... as if the inline "mouse enter" for the drawer cancelled out the image's "mouse leave".

Any suggestions?

Thank-you!

---

EDIT:

I believe I solved this by using .stop(true, false) when passing from the image and into the drawer.  This stops the animation dead before it even starts.  Then the same when entering the image BEFORE initiating the normal animation... this has the effect of stopping the animation triggered by leaving the drawer and entering the image but also does nothing when just entering the image normally.  More testing and then I'll post some sample code.

---

EDIT #2:

I have it working with "stop()" and "delay()" to control the animation but it's possible to freeze the opening of the drawer if you can get your mouse into it faster than it takes to open it.  Installed with 150 ms. but right now set to 300 ms to exaggerate the problem.

Relevant code posted here...

jsfiddle.net/qPLVp/8/

---

EDIT #3:

Thanks to Neil, this is functioning very well now.  With a quicker animation speed, the condition of a mouse overshooting the menu image and entering the drawer will be kept to a minimum.  But if it happens to occur, the drawer will not close which is much better than it closing from under your mouse.

http://jsfiddle.net/elusien/PayFw/8/

---

EDIT #4:

Again thanks to Neil, this is a more efficient version of the same code...

http://jsfiddle.net/PayFw/9/

Comment: Please show us the relevant bits of the jQuery code and the HTML to enable us to help. I think I can help, but I need to see the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your jsFiddle code to make it work. Basically I have attached a data object to your `#menu` element. When you are opening this drawer the object is `{opening: true}`. When the drawer is fully open (animation completed) the object is `{opening: false}`. I check this when you enter the drawer and if it is false, I stop the animation. If it is true I do NOT stop the animation.

The code is:

```
    function enter(event) { // mouseenter IMG
        // removed image rollover code

        $('#menu').data({opening: true}).stop(true, false).animate({
            top: '0',
            opacity: 1
        },{
            duration: 300  // slow the opening of the drawer
        },
        function(){$(this).data({opening: false});}
        );
    };
    function leave(event) { // mouseout IMG
        // removed image rollover code

        $('#menu').delay(400).animate({
            top: '-'+$ht+'px',
            opacity: 0
        },{
            duration: 600
        });
    };

    $('#menu').hover(
        function (){ // mouseenter Menu drawer
            if (!$(this).data('opening')) {
                $(this).stop(true, false);
            }
        },
        function (){ // mouseout Menu drawer
            $(this).delay(400).animate({
                top: '-'+$ht+'px',
                opacity: 0
            },{
                duration: 600    
            });

       }
   );
```

This now works fine. You might want to redo some of your "delay"s in light of this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PayFw/  Hi Neil- The above indeed fixes the problem of the freeze.  However, now the drawer will not stay open when the mouse moves into the drawer after animation completes.  Hover over menu image and wait for drawer to open.  Move mouse down into drawer and drawer closes.  You've certainly set me on the right path and with some adjustments, I think I can get this working.  Thank-you!

Comment: Based on your previous code, I have an idea, Neil... let me sort it out and I'll yell if I get stuck...  I appreciate your time and no sense you working on this if I'm about to solve it.  I'll post back either way.

Comment: Neil- I rewrote it and I thought I had something cool but moving the mouse around too fast just broke it.  The way you have it, the callback function never fires (syntax issue I think).  That part is fixed.  Now when you overshoot the menu image during animation, the drawer simply stops and closes.  You can only move inside the drawer when it's fully opened.  (ideally, I'd like the drawer to just finish opening & stay open when the mouse enters during animation).  Increasing duration will reduce the chance of failure.  Also interested in your wisdom... [link](http://jsfiddle.net/PayFw/5/)

Comment: Oh, (regarding JSFiddle in previous comment), moving back & forth between open drawer and menu image too fast causes the drawer to close.  This seems to be more challenging than expected.

Comment: Hi,I've fixed the problem. See http://jsfiddle.net/elusien/PayFw/8/. It was stopping the showing, rather than the hiding. You needed stop(true, true) and a couple of other changes to the data object. See the code. Good Luck.

Comment: I think we have a winner!  The second "true" in stop(true, true) causes the drawer to slam open when the mouse enters it during an animation, although without it, the drawer closes.  With a faster animation speed, this set of conditions is so rare that I'm not worried about it... it's a small price to pay for the extra robustness you've added.  I've learned a lot.  THANK-YOU!  One more thing... any idea how I can remove the redundancy in the identical closing animation being required by two different functions?  I've tried combining all the settings into a variable but my syntax must be wrong.

Comment: SParky, I'm just off to B&Q to buy some paint. "Her indoors" qants the bedrooms painting. I'll give it some thought this afternoon (or middle of the night for you).

Comment: Fixed - just replace the second "anonymouse" function on the "hover" by "leave". See the new code at: http://jsfiddle.net/PayFw/9/.

Comment: NEW VERSION. I've tried a different way of doing things, that may in the end be better. The basis is in my new answer below.

Comment: Thank-you for everything Neil!  I'll post back once I've had a chance to try out the two versions.

Comment: I never thought to re-use the "leave" function like that since "leave" is the "mouseout" function for the image and not the drawer.  However since the "mouseout" image is already showing, it's perfect... it just closes the drawer.  THANK-YOU for your help... everything is working great thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

Sparky,

I've come up with a different way of doing things. Basically putting a transparent mask over the "button" and "description" and using a "mouseleave" event on this.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="Container" class="menuContainer" style="position: relative">
<div id="menumask">&nbsp;</div>
<!-- this simulates the menu rollover image -->
<div id="menuitem" style="position:absolute; background-color:#ff00ff; top:10px; width:200px; height:50px; text-align:center;">
    <b>MENU ITEM</b>
</div>

<!-- this is the drawer -->
    <div id="menu" class="menuContent">
        <br/>
        <p>Content of the menu drawer.</p>
        <br/>
        <p>Bla bla bla </p>
        <br/>
        <p>Bla bla bla Bla.</p>
        <br/>
        <p>Bla bla bla Bla bla.</p>
        <br/>
        <p>Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla.</p>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menuitem').bind('mouseenter', enter);
    $('#menumask').bind('mouseleave', leave);

    $('#menu').css({
        height: '500px',
        position: 'absolute',
        paddingTop: '50px',
        width: '200px',
        backgroundColor: '#080',
        zIndex: -1
    }).hide();
    $('#menumask').css({
        height: '550px',
        width: '200px',
        opacity: 0.99,
        position: 'absolute',
        fontSize: '20000px',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        zIndex: 2
    }).hide();

    function enter(){
        $('#menumask').show();
        $('#menu').stop(true,true).animate({height: 500}, 'slow');
    };
    function leave(){
        $('#menumask').hide();
        $('#menu').stop(true,true).slideUp({height:   0}, 'slow');};  
});
```

You could use this as the basis for your menu system.

Regards
       Neil

Comment: Thank-you for everything Neil!  I'll post back once I've had a chance to try it out.

Comment: This code looks really good but for this site I'm not willing to make a mask for every button.  However it's going to get saved for future sites because it certainly solves a lot of issues with this concept.  Thank-you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking for the .delegate() function, which attaches a handler to a DOM event now or in the future:

```
$(".menuItem").delegate(".subMenu","hover", function(){ $(this).show(); });
```

You can read more about the .delegate() function and its buddy .live() here: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: Interesting.  Do you think this to be a better approach than the "stop" I'm playing with? (see my edit above and the suggestion by Neil below).  Delegate is new to me and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code it is difficult to know if the following would work:

`hover()` takes as its arguments 2 functions, the first is executed when you enter the image, the second; when you leave the image.

You have presumably set the second function to hide (close) the drawer. I would add a small delay (e.g. `delay(100)`) before the `hide()` and set a hover event on the drawer itself to (in the first function argument) stop the animation queue `stop(true, true)` - this will stop the drawer being closed, and in the second function - close the drawer when you exit it.

Comment: Thank-you Neil!... I figured out the "stop" before reading your answer but your idea of a small delay seems like a very smart addition to this.  I must use "stop(true, false)" though since I do not want the cancelled animation to complete.  Seems to work in Safari and Firefox... testing in Explorer next.

Comment: New to StackOverflow so not sure where to post all my code...  I got it working with one small problem... if I move the mouse over the image and into the drawer while it's opening, it freezes.  I have it opening pretty fast (200) to reduce this situation but it exists.

Comment: You can either put your code in the question itself (use the "code" symbol when you do it). or better still, put it on "www.jsfiddle.net" along with the HTML and CSS and post the web address you get when you save it so people then can easily "play" with it.

Comment: Concerning the "freezing", have you tried to increase the delay, say to 250?

Comment: Also, you may need a small delay on the HOVER into the drawer, so you don't kill the animation too soon and freeze like now.

Comment: My code is part of something pretty big... I think it might be a small project in itself just to trim it down to something meaningful for JSFiddle. (I guess I can't do carriage returns within these comments. I'm going to lay out the steps to freeze now and post code to my original question later.)  1.  hover image and drawer slides open within 200 ms.  2.  move mouse into drawer and animation to close drawer is stopped before it happens.  3.  Move mouse out of drawer and after a 400 ms delay, drawer closes with animation.  This is good.

Comment: However, if you move mouse too fast; here are new steps... 1. hover image and drawer slides open within 200 ms.  2.  IF your mouse moves into drawer in less than 200 ms, animation that's opening drawer is stopped.

Comment: And finally, despite email notifications being turned on, I cannot figure out how to make them work or change from "daily" to "instant".  I have received no notifications on this activity and nothing caught in spam.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I stumbled on this post while trying to accomplish the same thing. Thought I might leave my solution because it's now 2017, `.delegate` was deprecated, and using data to keep track of whether or not a transition was still in effect seemed messy.

The key was using the element passed into the `mouseleave` callback to get the `element.relatedTarget`.

```
$('.myMouseoverElements').on('mouseover', function() {        

  activeElements = $('.elements.to.open')
  activeElements.addClass('open')

  activeElements.on('mouseleave', function(element) {

    var sustainElements = $('.elements.to.sustain.mouseover')
    var drawerShouldClose = !$(element.relatedTarget).is(sustainElements)

    if (drawerShouldClose) {
      activeElements.removeClass("open")
      activeElements.off("mouseleave")
    }
  })
})
```

Thanks for the help!