# Cancel setTimeout if mouse is over div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two div classes, say A and B. When the mouse is over div A, div B should appear, then if the mouse is over A or B, div B should stay opened. If the mouse is out of both, A and B divs, B should disappear. (As you probably guess this is a simple tooltip script)

[image]

This is the jquery code I wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function show() {
        $("BBB").css({'display':'block'});
    }

    $("AAA").each(function() {
        $(this).mouseover(function() {
            show();
        });

        $(this).mouseleave(function() {
            time = setTimeout("hide()", 200);
        });

        $("BBB").mouseleave(function() {
            setTimeout("hide()", 200);
        });

        $("BBB").mouseenter(function() {
            clearTimeout(time);
        });
    });
});

function hide() {
    $("BBB").css({'display':'none'});
}
```

The problem is that when I move from B to A, B disappears! I want to it to disappear only if the mouse is neither over A, nor B. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This should help you.. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273566/how-do-i-check-if-the-mouse-is-over-an-element-in-jquery)

Comment: You do know jQuery has `.show()` and `.hide()` functions that do what your functions are doing, just say `$("BBB").show(); $("BBB").hide();`.

Comment: This is similar to the question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915977/keeping-a-sliding-menu-open-on-mouseover/4922792#4922792 See the 3 answers I posted and the JSFIDDLE code.

Comment: If you put your tooltip inside of the div that triggers it, a simple mouse over/out will work fine. See: http://jsfiddle.net/vfrQX/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few small problems with your code.  The one which is biting your right now is that you aren't clearing BBB's timeout when you enter AAA.  You can fix this by adding a `clearTimeout` to AAA's `mouseover` handler.

Secondly, it's safest to clear this kind of timeout before you set it each time, so that you don't have your timeout tracking overwritten if something unexpected happens.  (It's always safe to clear a timeout, even if it's invalid or has already occurred.)

Lastly, though this is most likely only a problem in your example code, you're leaking `time` into the global object.  ;-)

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var time;

    function show() {
        $("BBB").css({'display':'block'});
    }

    $("AAA").each(function() {
        $(this).mouseover(function() {
            clearTimeout(time);
            show();
        });

        $(this).mouseleave(function() {
            clearTimeout(time);
            time = setTimeout("hide()", 200);
        });

        $("BBB").mouseleave(function() {
            clearTimeout(time);
            time = setTimeout("hide()", 200);
        });

        $("BBB").mouseenter(function() {
            clearTimeout(time);
        });
    });
});

function hide() {
    $("BBB").css({'display':'none'});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, put `B` inside of `A`:

```
<div class="a">
    AAA
    <div class="b">
        BBB
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, abandon your javascript and make life easier with plain old css:

```
.b
{
    display: none;
}
.a:hover .b
{
    display: block;
}
```

**Edit** - Here's a live example using the CSS technique: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/sBwTa/1/

**Edit** - If you must use the JavaScript, just add `clearTimeout(time)` to `show()`.  But, let's also simplify your code:

```
$(function()
{
    var time = 0;
    function show()
    {
        clearTimeout(time);
        $("BBB").show(); // Existing jQuery that does $().css("display","block")
    }
    function hide()
    {
        time = setTimeout(function()
        {
            $("BBB").hide();
        }, 200);
    }
    $("AAA,BBB").mouseenter(show).mouseleave(hide);
});
```

Comment: What about those pesky IE6 users? This won't work while the mouse is over b either. It would if you added `.b:hover {display: block}`. However, most real life implementation end up being with script so you can allow for a little time before hiding showing elements and so the tip can follow the mouse (if it wants to)

Comment: Wrap it all up in an `<a>`.  Or don't bother... Are IE6 users really that important?  Seriously.  Maybe if you are writing online banking software.  Otherwise, weigh the financial incentive of retaining those users vs the cost of your time to support them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a script that works with meaningful function names that should make it easy to see what's going on. You have to cancel the hiding from `mouseenter` on both divs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timerId, delay = 300;
  var a = $("#A"),
    b = $("#B");

  function stopHide() {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
  }

  function showTip() {
    b.show();
  }

  function startHide() {
    timerId = setTimeout(function() {
      b.hide();
    }, delay);
  }
  a.mouseenter(showTip).mouseenter(stopHide).mouseleave(startHide);
  b.mouseenter(stopHide).mouseleave(startHide);
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 2px dashed firebrick;
  float: left;
  font-size: 50pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#B {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='A'> A </div>
<div id='B'> B</div>
```

Previously at http://jsfiddle.net/92jbK/1/

Answer (score 0):

You code is wrong :)
Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ru-RU">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #AAA, #BBB {
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            border:1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="BBB">
        BBB
    </div>
    <div id="AAA">
        AAA
    </div>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script>
        //VISIBLE 
        function hide() {
            $("#BBB").css({'display':'none'});
        }
        function show() {
            $("#BBB").css({'display':'block'});
        }

        // Load jQuery
        google.load("jquery", "1");
        google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
            // NOT VISIBLE
            // function hide() {
            //     $("#BBB").css({'display':'none'});
            // }
            // function show() {
            //     $("#BBB").css({'display':'block'});
            // }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                var time;

                $("#AAA").each(function() {
                    $(this).mouseover(function() {
                        show();
                    });

                    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
                        time = setTimeout("hide()", 200);
                    });

                    $("#BBB").mouseleave(function() {
                        setTimeout("hide()", 200);
                    });

                    $("#BBB").mouseenter(function() {
                        clearTimeout(time);
                    });
                });
            });


        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and for access to <div id="ID_NAME"></div> use $('#ID_NAME') not $('ID_NAME')

Answer (score 0):

one alternative is to use jquery's tooltip http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

then you can just do for example:

```
$('#A').live(function() {
      $(this).tooltip({
      relative: true,
      position: 'top center',
      delay: 200,
      effect: !$.browser.msie ? 'fade' : 'toggle',
      fadeInSpeed: 100,
      fadeOutSpeed: 50,
      predelay: 500
    });
  });
```

and you just make div b of class tooltip

Answer (score 0):

Is `time` declared outside all of this?

It is not in the same scope in the two functions you have it in above, so is not the same variable so the `clearTimeout()` call has no effect.

Declare it outside both with `var time;`, so that they refer to the same variable.